# Why won't my OJS 2.4.2 install start after going through the set up?

Tags: software-installation, php

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with php5.6 because it's an older software program. From the CLI I enter- PHP tools/install.php and the setup begins. After going through the prompts it says **"***Install Open Journal System [y/N]"**   I enter y, and nothing happens.

Comment: Did you press Enter too ?

Comment: Impossible to answer this... we need an error or notifications. Generally if nothing happens and you end with a new prompt it all went correct,

Comment: Yes, I pressed enter. lol